# Clipping the content of Canvas inside DataTemplate

Tags: wpf, xaml, datatemplate

I have a line inside Canvas as a root element on WPF window that looks fine. If I put it into the DataTemplate of ItemsControl then line will be looking clipped by StackPanel as a ItemsPanelTemplate. I've checked that other panels such as Grid as a ItemsPanelTemplate doesn't clip the content. I know that Canvas will not clip the content anyway. This appears in runtime only, not a design time. What is the root of problem?

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ...}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel ClipToBounds="False" 
                        Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Canvas Width="100"
                    Height="100" 
                    ClipToBounds="False">
                <Line X1="0"
                      Y1="0"
                      X2="-10"
                      Y2="10"
                      Stroke="DeepPink"
                      StrokeThickness="10" />
            </Canvas>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Its hard to tell without seeing a picture of what you want, however my best guess is the negative X2 value is causing the "clipping" effect you mention. When the `Canvas` is the root element, it centers the Canvas/Line, so it's not noticeable, but when it's in a `StackPanel` things are aligned to the left side, causing the clipping to be noticeable. If that is the case, change your X/Y values so you're not using a negative margin, such as `X1="10" Y1="10" X2="0" Y2="20"`

Comment: Thank you for fast response, Rachel. It will be too difficult for me. I want to see timeline rule is synchronized with events below on X axis. Instead of this I can move StackPanel as an ItemsPanelTemplate to avoid clipping, but this looks like workaround. It seems clipping is my doom. Sorry my bad english